# What is the default calling convention for exported functions (VS2008)?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, dllexport, calling-convention

Given the following C++ code which doesn't mention a calling convention in the function declaration, what will the calling convention be for the exported function `Exported`? My guess would be a default of cdecl.

```
extern "C"
{
  __declspec (dllexport) bool Exported(int parm);
}
```

I'm calling this function from managed code, using `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, and `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`. I can decorate my delegate definition with different values of the `UnmanagedFunctionPointer` attribute and they all *seem* to work.

Comment: Forcing the client programmer to explicitly use the CallingConvention property doesn't make a lot of sense, that just maximizes the odds of him getting it wrong.  Use __stdcall.  Also, explicitly calling LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress in the managed code is pretty unusual, the pinvoke marshaller already does this.

Comment: *explicitly calling LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress in the managed code is pretty unusual*. I agree.

Comment: BTW, I am the client programmer - I checked with me, and I don't mind having to specify CallingConvention ;¬)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default calling convention is cdecl. Note that __declspec(dllexport) has no influence on calling convention.

The calling convention can be specified in code, or by a compiler option. I don't recommend using the compiler option, it's a bit too obscure. Make it explicit in code and then anyone reading if knows what convention is used.

Note that for 64 bit Windows code, all calling conventions are equivalent which could explain what you see.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to modify the native code at the moment, but agree that explicitly specifying it in code is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

The default calling convetion also depends on some compiler switches:

Under c/c++ -> advanced you can set it:

/Gd = cdecl, /Gz = stdcall, /Gr = fastcall